# Vuejs - v-if not working with "!==" operator

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the npm package 'browser-detect' to check to see if the browser is Firefox. If it is Firefox, I don't want to render a particular . I am able to create a successful "v-if" functionality if I use the "===" operator, but I cannot seem to do the same thing with "!==", as shown here.

Here is the div:

```
<div v-if="browserName !== 'firefox'" class="zoom">
      <h4>Zoom Sheet:</h4>
      <p class="zoom-control">-</p>
      <input id="my-range" type="range" step="0.25" min="0.25" max="4" value="0.75" />
      <p class="zoom-control">+</p>
    </div>
```

Here is my import from detect-browser:

```
const { detect } = require('detect-browser');
const browser = detect();

let browserName = browser.name;
console.log('browser: ', browserName)
```

Here is what is in data:

```
data: {
browserName: this.browserName
}
```

Anyone have any clue as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `data: () => ({ browserName: browser.name })`

Comment: Thank you! That did it.